# nservicebus saga property injection with ninject

Tags: ninject, nservicebus, cqrs

I am using ninject when configuring NSB. Here is how I register:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    #region Implementation of IWantCustomInitialization

    public void Init()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        Configure.With().NinjectBuilder(kernel);

        kernel.Load(new BackendModule());
    }

    #endregion
}
public class BackendModule : NinjectModule
{
    #region Overrides of NinjectModule

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the module into the kernel.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IEventBus>().To<NsbBus>();
        Bind<IRecordStorageConfig>().To<RegistrationEventStorageConfig>();
        Bind<IRecordStorage>().To<RegistrationRecordStorage>();
        Bind<IRecordStorageFactory>().To<RegistrationRecordStorageFactory>();
        Bind<IAggregateRootFactory>().To<RegistrationFactory>();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I need the IAggregateRootFactory in the saga.

```
public class RegistrationSaga : Saga<RegistrationSagaData>,
                                IAmStartedByMessages<StartRegistration>,
                                IHandleMessages<CreateRegistration>,
                                IHandleMessages<ValidateRegistration>,
                                IHandleMessages<CancelRegistration>
{
    public RegistrationFactory Factory { get; set; }

    // removed implementation
}
```

The saga is started successfully and the commands are handlers are invoked. But the IAggregateRootFactory property injection is not working. The Factory is always null. Am I wiring this wrong?

Comment: NsbBus is just a wrapper and looks like this: public class NsbBus : IEventBus
    {
        private readonly IBus m_nsb;

        public NsbBus(IBus nsb)
        {
            m_nsb = nsb;
        }

        #region Implementation of IEventBus

        public void Publish<T>(T @event) where T : class, IEvent<IIdentity>
        {
            m_nsb.Publish(@event);
        }

        public void PublishAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> events) where T : class, IEvent<IIdentity>
        {
            foreach (var @event in events)
                m_nsb.Publish(@event);
        }

        #endregion
    }

Comment: I changed to Autofac and registered that factory as well but, factory is still null in the saga...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why your saga needs to have RegistrationFactory/IAggregateRootFactory in it, but it probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: That factory passes the command to AR. A handler in the saga would do something like Factory.ExecuteStoreDispatch(someCommand). The code is here. http://paste2.org/p/1986273

Comment: I think you're trying to move logic out of the saga to something else (what you're calling an aggregate root). I'm not sure I see the value in doing that.

Comment: The logic stays in the AR. Saga merely directs the commands to AR which will apply event from the result of that command to change its state. Saga stays clean. Please correct me if this is not the right usage of sagas.

Comment: One more thing Udi, beside the usage of factory, any ideas to why Ninject is not working for either property injection or ctor injection?

Comment: I did hear of problems around Ninject, specifically with regards to property injection. If all you want to do is route commands to some other object then you should be using a regular message handler - not a saga.