# NServiceBus, Could not find a saga for the message type

Tags: nservicebus

My saga below is not handling the ValidateRegistration and ValidateRegistration commands. I see the "Could not find a saga for the message type Registrations.Messages.ValidateRegistration with id ..." message.

Is my configuration to find saga not correct? Please help!

Thanks

PS: I am using the generic host in the registration process and I am using NServiceBus.Lite profile.

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    #region Implementation of IWantCustomInitialization

    public void Init()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(new BackendModule());

        //Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureProperty<RegistrationSaga>(x => x.Factory, kernel.Get<IAggregateRootFactory>());
        Configure.With().NinjectBuilder(kernel);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class RegistrationSagaData : IContainSagaData
{
    #region Implementation of ISagaEntity

    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Originator { get; set; }
    public virtual string OriginalMessageId { get; set; }

    public virtual RegistrationID RegistrationID { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsValidated { get; set; }
    public virtual string RegistrationType { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class RegistrationSaga : Saga<RegistrationSagaData>,
                                IAmStartedByMessages<StartRegistration>,
                                IHandleMessages<ValidateRegistration>,
                                IHandleMessages<CancelRegistration>
{
    public RegistrationFactory Factory { get; set; }

    public override void ConfigureHowToFindSaga()
    {
        ConfigureMapping<StartRegistration>(data => data.RegistrationID, registration => registration.ID);
        ConfigureMapping<ValidateRegistration>(data => data.RegistrationID, registration => registration.ID);
        ConfigureMapping<CancelRegistration>(data => data.RegistrationID, registration => registration.ID);
    }

    #region Implementation of IMessageHandler<StartRegistration>

    public void Handle(StartRegistration message)
    {
        Data.IsValidated = false;
        Data.RegistrationType = message.RegistrationType;

        Bus.SendLocal(new CreateRegistration
        {
            RegistrationType = message.RegistrationType,
            ID = message.ID
        });

        Console.WriteLine("======> handled StartRegistration");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IMessageHandler<ValidateRegistration>

    public void Handle(ValidateRegistration message)
    {
        MarkAsComplete();

        Console.WriteLine("======> handled ValidateRegistration");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IMessageHandler<CancelRegistration>

    public void Handle(CancelRegistration message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("======> handled CancelRegistration");

        MarkAsComplete();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler for StartRegistration is not adding RegistrationID to the Saga's Data. So your override of ConfigureHowToFindSaga is mapped on a property that's has no value when the other commands are handled.

Comment: You are correct. I realized that I missed it but it still didn't work. The problem was with the type of the RegistrationID property. It was of type RegistrationID. I used a Guid instead and it worked. I'll accept your answer though. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it would have worked, as long as your `RegistrationID` class implemented equality properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just today I heard that Ninject doesn't handle setter injection out of the box - try switching it over to constructor injection and see if that works.

Comment: Hi Udi, I just tried that but I get the "InvalidOperationException: Sagas which implement IConfigurable, liek tho.... must have a default constructor."

Comment: Hi again Udi, I think your answer applies to my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158739/nservicebus-saga-property-injection-with-ninject :)